# how to active subscription process with paypal DirectPayment method

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

We integrated PayPal Recurring Payment API **(PHP)** for subscription using express checkout and it is working fine. Now we are trying to integrate **DirectPayment** to accept credit/debit cards using **DoDirectPayment**. I send request to PayPal using **DoDirectPayment** method and it returns success in response and now i want to create recurring profile against this credit/debit card for future transactions. Now at this point if i call **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** method it requires TOKEN but i don't have any token returned in **DoDirectPayment** method response to create recurring profile. So please help and guide me the right process where is problem or i made any mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile only requires a token when used with Express Checkout.  For direct credit cards you'll use the same CRPP request, but you'll leave the token out and include the credit card parameters instead.

Here is a sample request that works just fine.

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => ****
        [PWD] => ****
        [VERSION] => 112.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => ****
        [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
        [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => Tester Testerson
        [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-06-27T00:00:00\Z
        [DESC] => Angell EYE Web Hosting
        [AUTOBILLAMT] => 1
        [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
        [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
        [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
        [AMT] => 10.00
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [CREDITCARDTYPE] => Visa
        [ACCT] => 4635800000971893
        [EXPDATE] => 022016
        [CVV2] => 123
        [STARTDATE] => 
        [ISSUENUMBER] => 
        [EMAIL] => tester@hey.com
        [BUSINESS] => Testers, LLC
        [FIRSTNAME] => Tester
        [LASTNAME] => Testerson
        [STREET] => 123 Test Ave.
        [CITY] => Grandview
        [STATE] => MO
        [COUNTRYCODE] => US
        [ZIP] => 64030
    )
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean with CRPP request??

Comment: CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Comment: can you please tell me how can i check is profile created or not against credit card for sandbox???

Comment: If you run the CRPP request and get a successful response back then you know the profile was created.  You would also get an IPN if you have that configured.

Comment: can u give me full demo for this with laravel

Comment: @JigneshsinhRathod Take a look at this:  http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com/.  That is a Laravel isntall with our library to rebuild the PayPal interface functionality (and show off what our library can do.)  It's available on GitHub here (https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass).  You can see how our library works within Laravel and then use it for yourself.